# Stylus: expected "indent", got "outdent"

Tags: css, stylus

I'm new in stylus. Trying to make list of rules such as `.mt--20, .mt--30, .mt--35 etc.`

I got this error

[image]

My stylus code:

```
margin(postfix, side, numbers)
  .m{postfix}
    for n in numbers
      &--{n}
        margin-{side} {n}px
    for n in numbers
      &--{n}-xs
        @media $media-max-1366
          margin-{side} {n}px
    for n in numbers
      &--{n}-lg
        @media $media-min-1366
          margin-{side} {n}px

list = 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 55 60

margin(b, bottom, list)
margin(t, top, list)
margin(l, left, list)
margin(r, right, list)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For 1 you don't need all the for statements as they all do the same. My guess for the problem is that all the for statements are directly after each other. Maybe by adding an enter/ line break after each it will work as it knows what the end of the loops is

Comment: @SuperDJ why answer the question in a comment?

Comment: @SuperDJ For the first time I tried to write it with only one for statement but there was the same problem

Comment: Is margin supposed to be a mixin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is with your interpolation of `n`. after the `margin-{side}` you don't need to interpolate.

**Solution:**

```
margin(postfix, side, numbers)
  .m{postfix}
    for n in numbers
      &--{n}
        margin-{side} n px
      &--{n}-xs
        @media $media-max-1366
          margin-{side} n px
      &--{n}-lg
        @media $media-min-1366
          margin-{side} n px

list = 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 55 60

margin(b, bottom, list)
margin(t, top, list)
margin(l, left, list)
margin(r, right, list)
```

Here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/whosdustin/pen/LJXLje) where you can view the compiled source (without errors).